# Safari text-alignment has me stumped

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I am having a hard time understanding what to do to prevent Safari (on a Mac) from playing havoc with the alignment of a paragraph element, nested within some divs.

The problem can be seen using Safari web browser at [www.redkitesmusic.com/redkites](http://www.redkitesmusic.com/redkites) 
After loading the page, select THE BAND.

Here is what I get in Safari:

[image: badly formatted in Safari]

And here is what I get in Chrome (and others)

[image: nicely formatted in Chrome]

I have tried to work this out using the web developer inspector but can't figure out what's wrong.

HTML and CSS follow.

**Thank you** if you can make some sense of my problem and offer a possible solution!

This is the HTML snippet:

```
<div id="divPopupContent" style="display: block;" class="bios">
<div style="float:left;width:30%">
    <p>About me: I was born in Cameroon in 1989 but have lived in The Highlands of Scotland for most of my life. In 2010 I dropped out of my Ecology course in Aberdeen and moved to Guildford to form a band…</p>
```

And this is the CSS which applies

```
#divPopupContent {
    background-color: #EEF;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    color: #333;
    float: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 92%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin-left: 6px;
    /*margin-top: -18px;*/
    margin-top: 6px;
    overflow:  hidden;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    position: relative;
    width: 72%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#divPopupContent.bios {
    width: 78%;
}

#divPopupContent div:first-child {
    height: 97%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of font that you are using. 
On some version of safari browser, font can't be displayed properly.

Comment: Do you know what?, you're spot-on, thank you. I eventually returned to the problem yesterday - with a Mac to hand - and suddenly I had a flash of inspiration that the .ttf might be the problem. I removed it and reverted to simple 'serif' and it all worked fine.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty weird. When I put your code into a Codepen in my Safari browser (Version 7.0 (9537.71), Mac OS 10.9), it looks perfectly normal:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JjhKk

Does that Codepen look weird in your Safari?

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking.  Will test that and reply soon,

Comment: It looks fine. Perhaps I have to conclude that it is some outer component setting which is upsetting matters.